# how to arrange two divs one beside other horizontally where both the div has html tables?

Tags: css, html

I have three div one is main div, one div having two column table and another div has 5 column table. I have tried using bootstrap class "row" but I did not able to align them properly. How can I arrange this two div one beside another?  Here below I have attached a picture. Can anyone please help me out for this problem.

[image]

here below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>trial</title>

    <!--Links for icons and images-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <!--css for paginated-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Performance/css/usermange.css">

    <style>
    #displayproject{
       margin-top:100px;
       position:fixed;
       background-color:blue;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="displayproject">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Projects</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        include_once "../Connection/dbconnect.php";
                        $fetch_projects = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['db'],"select project_id,project_name from project_table limit 10;");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_projects)){
                            echo '<tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="hello">
                                        <label></label>
                                    </span>
                                </td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row['project_name'].'</td></tr><tr></tr>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>Manage <b>Employees</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Employee</span></a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i> <span>Delete</span></a>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                            </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                                <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Thomas Hardy</td>
                        <td>thomashardy@mail.com</td>
                        <td>89 Chiaroscuro Rd, Portland, USA</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="options[]" value="1">
                                <label for="checkbox3"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Maria Anders</td>
                        <td>mariaanders@mail.com</td>
                        <td>25, rue Lauriston, Paris, France</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output I am getting is

[image]

Comment: set first div property float: left; and second div property display:inline-block; or display:inherit

Comment: it's not relevant to php

Comment: okay I will remove tag php @TarangP

Comment: if I set second div as inherit, the output is same. If I set display: inline-block, the second div is showing behind first div @sandy

Comment: have you add the first div property as flot:left ?

Comment: yes I have added @sandy

Comment: set the property like .left {
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px 10px;
  display: inline;
} change the name of the class according to your view

Comment: Your HTML didn't load `bootstrap.css`. If you add that tag, then it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap 3 , you can see the code here
https://codepen.io/shakercs/pen/MBgwQJ

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      div is here 
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>checkbox</th>
          <th>name</th>
          </tr>
         
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr> <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
       <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>checkbox</th>
          <th>name</th>
            <th>title</th>
          <th>title</th>
          </tr>
         
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>  <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>  <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>  <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>  <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>  <tr>
            
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
          </tr>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `float:value;` property of `css` to achieve this.

```
value:left|right|clear
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>trial</title>

    <!--Links for icons and images-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

    <!--css for paginated-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/Performance/css/usermange.css">

    <style>
    #displayproject{
       float:left;
       margin-top:100px;
       position:fixed;
       background-color:blue;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="displayproject">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Projects</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="table-wrapper" style="float:right;">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>Manage <b>Employees</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="#addEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE147;</i> <span>Add New Employee</span></a>
                        <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i> <span>Delete</span></a>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                <label for="selectAll"></label>
                            </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                                <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Thomas Hardy</td>
                        <td>thomashardy@mail.com</td>
                        <td>89 Chiaroscuro Rd, Portland, USA</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="options[]" value="1">
                                <label for="checkbox3"></label>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>Maria Anders</td>
                        <td>mariaanders@mail.com</td>
                        <td>25, rue Lauriston, Paris, France</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there will be gap at the center if I set float left and right

Comment: you need to set the width property according and make sure that you didn't set margin|padding property which will lead to this issue.

Comment: as you are using bootstrap classes may be into this classes width,margin or padding property is set so you need to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you -

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        First div
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="border:1px solid">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>col</td>
            <td>col</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12"  style="border:1px solid">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>col</td>
            <td>col</td>
            <td>col</td>
            <td>col</td>
            <td>col</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is an example code. You can modify accordingly.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/75603/)